# Wifi extension using router in bridge mode - still need to reconnect

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge-router, wireless-extender

Since my Verizon Fios router is at one end of my house, so the wifi signal is weak on the other side of the house, I decided to take my old Linksys E3200 router and hook it up in bridge mode. I followed the main instructions here http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=132275 for a Lan-to-Lan connection using a Cat-6 cable, with the addition that I put the Linksys router in Bridge Mode (under Type of Internet Connection) (as noted on this page http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=137888 under "Step 7")

I now have a much stronger signal at the other end of the house where the Linksys router is. And because it is in bridge mode, then when I go to connect a device (such as my android phone or my macbook) I see only one Wifi listed (as I want and expect).

***The problem is this***: *Once I am connected to my wifi, then if I walk to the other end of the house with my device (phone or laptop) the device remains connected to the first router I connected to (either the Verizon, or the Linksys).*

*If I disconnect and reconnect, then upon reconnection my device automatically connects to the closer router; but then the same issue happens again if I now walk to the other end of the house.*

***My question is this:*** **Is there any way I can configure this setup so that my device will remain seamlessly connected to the network as a whole, no matter where I am?** (That's how things seem to work when I am walking from floor to floor in the office where I work).

Answer (score 1):

The decision to roam from one AP to another is entirely up to the client.  You could reduce the power of both devices so that your clients are forced to roam earlier.  Of course, that may affect performance in other parts of your house -- you'll have to experiment and see.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how I would reduce the power.  Would it possibly help if I configure each router to use a specific wifi channel (for example set one router on channel 11 and the other on 6)?  I saw that suggested here:http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx under technical summary

Comment: That's not going to help.  The problem is your device can still connect to the far end AP well enough so it doesn't roam.  If you reduce the power, making to usable range smaller, it will be forced to roam earlier.

Comment: Another question (will play with the power thing over the weekend, but in the meantime, just wondering ...) Is there anything I can configure on the client (i.e. my phone) to make it want to roam to a stronger signal sooner?